# DatabaseMetadata.getColumns issue with sql server jdbc driver

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to get metadata for a table having special characters in table name. In normal scenario my code works fine but i have a table "TABLE[]}\|ABC" in which getColumns is not returning any value.

```
ResultSet rrc = meta.getColumns("SCHEMA_NAME", null, "TABLE_NAME", "%");
```

Also there is something strange behavior i found. Just pass your schema name in first parameter and pass any other value in rest of the 3 parameters.

```
 ResultSet rrc = meta.getColumns("SCHEMA_NAME", null, null, "%");
 while (rrc.next()) {
    System.out.println("-- col: " + rrc.getString(4));
 }
```

Just change `rrc.getString(4)(COLUMN_NAME)` to `rrc.getString(3)(TABLE_NAME)` or add other combinations and find number of record you are receiving for the same resultset. It will vary based on your selection.

Comment: Is that table really named `TABLE[]}\|ABC` ? Also, I have no clue what you mean with the second part of your question. You might want to add some clarification there.

Comment: Yes. Table Name is "TABLE[]}\|ABC"

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of [`DatabaseMetaData.getColumns(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is called `tableNamePattern`. It is a `LIKE` pattern, not a literal. In a `LIKE`-pattern, the backslash(`\`) is an escape character. So, if you want to match a table named `TABLE[]}\|ABC`, you will need to use the pattern `TABLE[]}\\|ABC` (note the double slash), which as a Java string would be `"TABLE[]}\\\\|ABC"`.

Comment: While sending 3rd parameter i am using "\\" which is obvious as Java considers '\' as escape character. But i don't think that is an issue.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking from a purely SQL standpoint, as a Java string, you will need to use `\\\\\`.

Comment: Table has only one \ but from Java perspective i need to escape it so i have added one more \. That's the reason table has 2 backslash.

Comment: But you need to treat the parameter as an SQL `LIKE` pattern. In an SQL `LIKE` pattern, the `\ ` is an escape, so you need to use `\\ `, and as its a Java string you need to escape it again, so it becomes `\\\\ `. You basically need to think of it as a query that does `SELECT * FROM table_info WHERE tablename LIKE <tableNamePattern>`, using (as an SQL literal, not a Java string!) `'TABLE[]}\|ABC'` in that query wouldn't work, but using `'TABLE[]}\\|ABC'` would.

Comment: tried but still not working.. if i put "%" in 3rd parameter and compare using getString("TABLE_NAME") with "TABLE[]}\\|ABC" it works but if i pass "TABLE[]}\\|ABC" as 3rd parameter of getColumns it doesn't work.